# android - W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection

Tags: java, android

I'm working in Android Studio and I get:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

every time I enter anything into my EditTexts. It doesn't seem to be fatal but I'd like to know really what it means and how to fix it.